# The value of p in a Standard deviation of a binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

The random variable $X$ has a binomial distribution $b(n,p)$. For what value of $p$ is the standard deviation of $X$ the greatest (note: the answer is independent of $n$).

Can someone help with this question! I know the formula of standard deviation, it's $\sqrt{n p( 1 - p)}$. My question is: Are we trying to find a value closest to zero? Can anyone explain and help to find the value of $p$?

Comment: You have the expression $n p (1-p)$ which is in fact the *variance*.  The *standard deviation* would be $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$. You want to find the value of $p$ which maximises the latter (and this will also maximise the former).  As a hint, $p(1-p) = \frac14-\left(p - \frac12\right)^2$

Comment: what do you mean by latter and former?

Comment: You said originally you wanted to find "for what value of $p$ is the standard deviation of $X$ the greatest"

Comment: yes correct @Henry

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What you want to do is find $p\in[0,1]$ such that the function
$$ f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R, \quad p \mapsto np(1-p),$$
attains its maximum in $p$. You can use straight-forward calculations or brute force (this function is twice differentiable).

Comment: Still a bit confused